# iOS:iPhone Dev: Where are the MVC and whats the delegate classes are for?

Tags: model-view-controller, ios, delegates

I have been reading articles about iOS development. But I still cannot get the MVC framework in iOS development. I do know the MVC in cakephp, but where are the MVC in cocoa? Here are my guess:

1. Model => classes, like core data?
2. View => nib/xib files
3. Controller => view controller files?

And I dont get the delegate classes, what are these classes for? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998818/where-does-the-appdelegate-file-fit-into-mvc

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest watching some of the Stanford iOS Development course videos on iTunesU. Helped me a ton. This instructor explains exactly what you are asking in great detail.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522

Good luck.

Comment: I see. I guess u already watched it, why dont you share the answer or explain what you understand here, so that new iphone developers can find similar answers in this page? The videos are too long lol

Answer (score 0):

I started to watch Stanford iOS videos and I had the same doubt. I found a similar question here at stack overflow and a great answer which can help you urderstand.

**Is a delegate analogous to a mvc controller?** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507588/968144