# Is a delegate analogous to a mvc controller?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, delegates, controller

I saw this article:

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/10/01/cocoa-touch-tutorial-iphone-application-example/

"Delegate == Controller
The words delegate and controller can be used synonymously...."

I'm not sure what he is saying but I understand mvc better than I do delegates in programming.

Are the two similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are really on different levels.

A Class that uses a Delegate is a Class (any Class) designed so that custom behaviour can be provided by another object instead of, say, by subclassing.

*e.g.* most Cocoa Apps will want to do something custom on app launch (pretty boring if they didn't). Instead of requiring every Cocoa App to implement a custom Subclass of `NSApplication` just to override `–applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, `NSApplication` is designed so that if you set it's `delegate` property to valid object, and that object has an `–applicationWillFinishLaunching:` method it will call that.

That way you can use any Class you like for your setup, you don't have to make it a Subclass of NSApplication.

Many Cocoa Classes work like this, meaning you hardly ever have to subclass them to add custom behaviour. In some other languages and frameworks the way you are supposed to add your custom behaviour is by subclassing. Want a custom button in java? Just create a new Class that extends JComponent and implements MouseListener then override mouseClicked, etc. This is not the Cocoa way.

A controller, as you know, is an Object responsible for coordinating the Model and the View.

As it happens, if you need to add custom behaviour to an instance of a Model Object or a View Object - say for example you have an NSTableView object and you want to add custom behaviour when a row is selected - you probably already have a custom Controller object and this is often the perfect place to put the code. Just set the TableView's.delegate = controller. We can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSTableViewDelegate) that tableView has a delegate method `- tableViewSelectionDidChange:` You don't have to create a subclass of NSTableView.

I don't consider this to mean that a Delegate and a Controller are the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are the background processes running to catch an event. They are the controller as you recognize them from our friendly MVC software engineering dynamic. An event could be a button push screen touch shake etc.... Delegate is the word Coccoa uses to be distinct which as the author of your how to guide puts it makes them "interchangeable". Hope this helps