# Are these points about delegates in IOS correct? Yes or no?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I've been struggling with delegates for a long time. It's a very hard concept for me for some reason. I feel like now I have more knowledge, but I'm still far from being confident.

Please tell me if any of these are incorrect/incomplete and why. Thank you.

1. Delegates implement protocols (unimplemented method headers)
2. An object (a delegator) can register a delegate (that implements a protocol). This can be done by declaring a property of type id that implements a protocol:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) id <MyProtocol> myDelegate;
   ```
3. The delegator can call certain methods (as specified in MyProtocol protocol) on the delegate
4. Any class that implements the protocol and has to be Delegator's delegate, can declare itself as such:

   ```
   MyDelegator* myDelegator = segue.destinationViewController;
   myDelegator .delegate = self;
   ```
5. Advantages of using a delegate:

   a. Reduces coupling (Delegate and Delegator are no longer dependent on each other) which is an important OO design principle

   b. makes Delegator more generic; it can now work with other objects, not just this Delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1,2 - yes

3 - can call any method of MyProtocol,

4 - correct.

5 - almost right, a very good explanation can be found here [delegate and controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495466/is-a-delegate-analogous-to-a-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.  But the protocols can be [informal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html).
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. Yes and no.  Again, the delegate *could* implement the methods informally... but then you'd want the delegator to verify if the delegate [`respondsTo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a) (or implements) a method before calling it.

   The delegate doesn't necessarily need to set itself as the delegator's delegate (in fact, it shouldn't).  **Analogy:** A business specialist comes to my company and tells my boss to delegate the administrative paperwork to his secretary.  The secretary (the delegate) didn't tell the boss (the delegator) to give it work... a third-party did.

   A delegate doesn't have to register itself as the delegate (again, it shouldn't).  It needs only be able to do the work.  Normally the delegate would know nothing (no pointers to) the delegator. So the delegate wouldn't have `MyDelegator* myDelegator = segue.destinationViewController;`, no.
5. A) Yes!

   B) Yes. Essentially what "reduce coupling" is;

   Adding a C): It also allows you to change the behaviour on-the-fly by simply changing the delegate at runtime.